# Using CMake in mingw32 for a Fortran code

Tags: cmake, fortran, mingw32

Here is a simple question, I need to create a CMake builder onto mingw32. I want to define the compiler in the CMakeLists.txt (although I want to specify that when calling cmake later). The txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles")
message("generator is set to ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")

#set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/PGI/win64/15.10/bin")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95")
```

and it returns:

```
generator is set to MinGW Makefiles
-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files     (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95  -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-   3.4/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
The Fortran compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95" is not able
to compile a simple test program.
```

What do I do wrong ? I understand it does not find the compiler correctly. Thank you for your help.

Edit. As suggested I post the CMakeError.log

```
Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file    "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -v

The output was:
Access is denied


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file    "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
Access is denied


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file  "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
Access is denied


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Silverfrost/FTN95 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -fpp

 The output was:
 Access is denied


 Checking whether the Fortran compiler is Compaq using "-what" did not match   "Compaq Visual Fortran":
 Checking whether the Fortran compiler is NAG using "-V" did not match "NAG     Fortran Compiler":
 Determining if the Fortran compiler works failed with the following output:
 Change Dir:    C:/Users/RolandGuichard/Desktop/SATURN/SATGPU/testcm/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

 Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio    14.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"   "cmTC_e9efb"
 The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created.
```

Any more information I can track here ? Thank you.

Comment: There must be some more complete log file with the actual compilation error.

Comment: Yes, would it help ?

Comment: Who knows, without seeing it. You should definitely post it.

Comment: Check CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log in your build directory, too.

Answer (score 0):

To help others: After 4 years, i have hit the same issue. I solved it by making sure you point to the exact location of the FORTRAN executable in your `CMakeList.txt` like this : `set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gfortran.exe")`. This solves it for me. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As the Visual Studio generator does not support MinGW gfortran. They are totally separate ecosystems. Remove your build directory and create a fresh one.

so to define the generator what works for me is to define the it using a flag in the command line

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

I have tried also to set the CMAKE_GENERATOR as a variable inside the CMakefile.txt

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles")
```

but for some reason, it did not work and I have to pass the generator in the command line